# Inconsistent output from gcount()

Tags: c++, stringstream, stringtokenizer, string-view

I have written the following simple MRE that regenerates a bug in my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// this function is working fine only if string_view contains all the user provided chars and nothing extra like null bytes
std::pair< bool, std::vector< std::string > > tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr, const std::size_t expectedTokenCount )
{
    // unnecessary implementation details

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << inputStr.data( ); // works for null-terminated strings, but not for the non-null terminated strings

    // unnecessary implementation details
}

int main( )
{
    constexpr std::size_t REQUIRED_TOKENS_COUNT { 3 };
    std::array<char, 50> input_buffer { };

    std::cin.getline( input_buffer.data( ), input_buffer.size( ) ); // user can enter at max 50 characters

    const auto [ hasExpectedTokenCount, foundTokens ] { tokenize( { input_buffer.data( ), input_buffer.size( ) }, REQUIRED_TOKENS_COUNT ) };

    for ( const auto& token : foundTokens ) // print the tokens
    {
        std::cout << '\'' << token << "' ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This is a program for tokenization (for full code see **Compiler Explorer** at the link below). Also, I use *GCC v11.2*.

First of all, I want to avoid using `data()` since it's a bit less efficient.

I looked at the assembly in [**Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/dWr5jj3rG) and apparently, `data()` calls `strlen()` so when it reaches the first null byte it stops. But what if the `string_view` object is not null-terminated? That's a bit concerning. So I switched to `ss << inputStr;`.

Secondly, when I do this `ss << inputStr;`, the whole 50 character buffer is inserted into `ss` with all of its null bytes. Below are some sample outputs that are wrong:

sample #1:

```
1                  2    3
'1' '2' '3                                     ' // '1' and '2' are correct, '3' has lots of null bytes
```

sample #2 (in this one I typed a space character after 3):

```
1                  2    3
'1' '2' '3' '                                     ' // an extra token consisting of 1 space char and lots of null bytes has been created!
```

Is there a way to fix this? What should I do now to also support ***non-null terminated*** strings? I came up with the idea of `gcount()` as below:

```
    const std::streamsize charCount { std::cin.gcount( ) };
                                                                                        // here I pass charCount instead of the size of buffer
    const auto [ hasExpectedTokenCount, foundTokens ] { tokenize( { input_buffer.data( ), charCount },
                                                                    REQUIRED_TOKENS_COUNT ) };
```

But the problem is that when the user enters less characters than the buffer size, `gcount()` returns a value that is 1 more than the actual number of entered `char`s (e.g. user enters 5 characters but `gcount` returns 6 apparently also taking '\0' into account).

This causes the last token to also have a null byte at its end:

```
1   2     3
'1' '2' '3 ' // see the null byte in '3 ', it's NOT a space char
```

How should I fix `gcount`'s inconsistent output?

Or maybe I should change the function `tokenize` so that it gets rid of any '\0' at the end of the `string_view` and then starts to tokenize it.

It might sound like an XY problem though. But I really need help to decide what to do.

Comment: Why does the view have a range that includes embedded `'\0'` bytes in the first place?  I'd fix that code in the caller.

Comment: @Eljay So you mean that `tokenize` should not handle the extra null bytes and it's the caller's responsibility to remove them from the view? I tried to do that but `gcount` causes problems.

Comment: `gcount` returns the number of read past in cin's buffer *including any newline* or other delimiter that may have been discarded by getline or getdelim. Has nothing to do with any NULs, and depends on the buffer management as well (so for a very long input line that involved an `underflow` it will be less)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem you have is with the `operator<<` functions.  You've tried two of them:

- `operator<<(ostream &, const char *)` which will take characters from the pointer up to (and not including) the next NUL.  As you've noted, that may be a problem if the pointer comes from a string_view without a terminating NUL.
- `operator<<(ostream &, const string_view &)` which will take all the characters from the string_view including any NULs that may be present.

It seems that what you want to do is take characters from the string_view up to (and not including) the first NUL or the end of the string_view, whichever comes first.  You can do that with `find` and constructing a substr up to the NUL or end:

```
ss << inputStr.substr(0, inputStr.find('\0'));
```

Comment: I tried this and it's brilliant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you think about `remove_suffix`? Can this also be done using that?

Comment: I guess `if (inputStr.find('\0') != npos) inputString.remove_suffix(inputStr.size() - inputStr.find('\0'));` would do it, but seems like much more work, particularly as `substr` does exactly what you want without needing a test for npos.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a bit more work. Your solution is good and should suffice.